# Customized yearly resampling pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I found that any dataframe can be resampled using `df[columns].resample('Y').mean()`. But I want to customize so that the resampling yearly but only happens for customized months. For example, from April to October for each year. Is it possible to do so using pandas? I checked the official documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/resampling.html) but could not find solution. Can anyone please put some light on it?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any direct pandas operation. But filtering did solve it.

First create another dataset with only desired months:

```
resampled_data = resampled_data[df['date].month <= 9]
```

(here 9 menas september)

' Now performing the Resampling

```
resampled_data = resampled_data.resample("Y").mean()
```

But the "date" will be changed to the end date of the year.
So, changing the index till the month of data available.

```
resampled_data['date']= resampled_data['date'] - pd.DateOffset(month=3)
```

During the filtering at the first step, we can also filter by discarding the start months as much as needed. For example,

```
resampled_data = resampled_data[df['date].month >= 3]
```

(here 3 means March)